# Using scanf/printf to input into/output from a bitset

Tags: c++, printf, scanf, std-bitset

I'm somewhat new to C++, and I was wondering how to scanf into or printf out of a bitset, i.e., what is the appropriate type specifier for I/O to a bitset index? An example of what I would want to do is:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std; 

int main() 
{
    bitset<1> aoeu;
    scanf("%d" &bitset[0]); //this line
    printf("%d" bitset[0]); // this line
}
```

Comment: Why? If you're using C++, then use C++ features (like `cin`/`cout`). You can use [to_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_string) then print out its char array.

Comment: You cannot use `scanf` directly with bitsets, because `scanf` requires an address to a byte, not a bit. However, you can first use `scanf` to write to a byte (`unsigned char`) or an `int` and then convert it to bits for the bitset.

Answer (score 3):

As ChrisMM mentioned, you should use the the C++ way of doing input and output. Luckily, a [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) has overloads for `operator<<` and `operator>>` so you directly read from `std::cin` and write to `std::cout`, without needing `to_string()`, like so:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
 
int main() 
{
    std::bitset<1> aoeu;
    std::cin >> aoeu; // read bitset from standard input
    std::cout << aoeu; // write bitset to standard output
}
```

If you just want to read one specific bit and put it in a bitset, you have to do it a bit more indirect:

```
std::bitset<3> bits;
int value;
std::cin >> value; // read one integer, assuming it will be 0 or 1
bits[1] = value; // store it in the second bit of the bitset
```

Comment: You did not answer the OP's main question on how to accomplish this using `scanf` and `printf`. Since the OP's question probably is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), you were correct to show the OP the correct way to solve the underlying problem, without using `scanf` and `printf`. Therefore, I have upvoted your answer. However, for completeness, I have written my own answer, in which I answer the OP's question on how it can be accomplished with `scanf` and `printf`.

Answer (score 3):

Your question on how to accomplish this with `scanf` and `printf` seems to be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). The answer provided by @GSliepen shows you how to do it properly in C++.

However, in case you are really interested on how to accomplish this using `scanf` and `printf` (which I don't recommend), I will give you a direct answer to your question:

You cannot use `scanf` directly with bitsets, because `scanf` requires an address to at least a byte, not a single bit. Addresses to single bits don't even exist (at least on most platforms). However, you can first use `scanf` to write to a temporary byte (`unsigned char`) or an `int` and then convert it to a bit for the bitset, for example like this:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>

int main() 
{
    std::bitset<1> aoeu;
    int ret, input;

    ret = std::scanf( "%d", &input );
    assert( ret == 1 );

    aoeu[0] = input;

    std::printf( "%d\n", static_cast<int>(aoeu[0]) );
}
```

In case you are wondering why I am not `using namespace std;`, although you do in your question, then you may want to read [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/12149471).

Answer (score 0):

To print the value of a specific bit *j*
`printf("%d", aoeu(j));`

To print the value of the whole bitset I would suggest using

`printf("%s\n", val.to_string().c_str());`